# Why variable is not change value?

Tags: angular

There is a varaible `public loading: boolean;` in component class.

Also there is a method that set loading to true and to false:

```
public createDocument() {
    try {
        if (this.isOpenDialog) throw 'Dialog already opened!';

        this.loading = true;
        this.isOpenDialog = true;

        this.documentService.loadDocuments(this.application.reglamentid).then((response) => {
            this.documentService.setTypeDocuments(response.typedocuments);
            this.loading = false;

            this.documentDialogFormService
                .open({ title: 'Формирование проекта документа', appid: this.application.appId })
                .subscribe(() => {
                    this.isOpenDialog = false;
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
    }
}
```

When I get data from server I set it to   `this.loading = false;`.

But in template `{{loading}}` it is still `true`, why?

Comment: Did you try to logging the variable ?
What is you changeDetection set to ?

Also, non relevent, but why do you set loading to false two times ?

Comment: Yes, in debugger I see it as `false`, but in template as true. I use `    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,`

Comment: Perhaps your 'this' is not the scope that is used in the template? To my knowledge primitive variables should be updated in the template if changed in the model. If it would have been a nested object you would have to tell the template that it has updated but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With changeDetection set to OnPush, the change detection will only be triggered into the following situations :

- DOM events
- the variable is an @Input and its value changed
- a variable is used with an `async` pipe and its value changed
- by triggering the change detection manually

In your situation you can either :

- remove the changeDetection (or set it to Default)
- use an `async` pipe (as answered by TheAngularGuy)
- inject ChangeDetectorRef inside your consctructor and use `.markForCheck()` when needed

Comment: Its more performant to call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` istead than `.detectChanges()` as the later will check all the view all its childrens. More info [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: indeed, i changed my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is a change detection problem, you can read more about the `onPush` pitfalls [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/).

Try converting your variable to a BehaviorSubject. So you have a template like this:

```
{{ loading$ | async }}
```

And you have a `.ts` like this:

```js
loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
...
createDocument() {
  ...
  this.loading$.next(true);
  ...
  this.documentService.loadDocuments(this.application.reglamentid).then((response) => {
    this.loading$.next(false);
    ...
  });
}
```

---

**Tip:** Since it's a BehaviorSubject you can access its value synchronously in your `.ts` file using `loading$.getValue()`.